# Dava da mangiare: Imperfect past tense of "feed"?

Tags: meaning, translation

I've got a Duolingo question phrased like this:

> Il contadino dava da mangiare al cavallo ogni giorno.

My best attempt at translation is something like:

"The farmer gave his horse from hunger every day"

Is this related to how one "has hunger"? (Ho fame) Is it just a difference of thinking about the sentiment?

Comment: "mangiare" means "to eat". it has little to do with "hunger", which is "fame".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the correct translation is:

> The farmer fed his horse every day.

or

> The farmer gave something to eat to his horse every day

In Italian "dare da mangiare" (lit. "to give [something] to eat") means "to feed", and it has nothing to with "being hungry" (i.e. "avere fame").

Maybe one of the reasons you are confused is that you are translating *da* with "from". But in this case this is not the correct translation: it should be translated with *to* (i.e. it introduces the aim of the action, not its provenance). Unfortunately prepositions are very hard to translate between different languages.

Answer (score 1):

The two words together, "da mangiare", can mean "food", constructed with "da" like, for example,

- macchina da scrivere ("machine for writing", typewriter)
- legna da ardere (wood to burn)
- cera da candela (vax for candles)

(Note that similar forms are not always good italian, but are widely used; for example *macchina da scrivere* is often considered an error, but is much more common than *macchina **per** scrivere*).

About *da mangiare*, the real meaning is "[cosa buona] da mangiare" ("good to eat", or "appropriate to be eaten"), like *legna da ardere* which means "wood good for burning".

The following phrases can be seen normally:

- compro da mangiare  (I buy food)
- serve da mangiare (food is needed)
- siamo senza roba da mangiare (we have no food)
- abbiamo niente da mangiare (same)
- siamo senza da mangiare (same; incorrect, but used)
- dagli da mangiare (give some food to him)

Now, "dare da mangiare" has two nuances, "to give food" or "to feed". Probably a farmer *feeds* his horse, where a wife *gives food* to her husband (unless he needs assistance).